# alternative (faster) way to 3 nested for loop python

Tags: python

How can I make this function faster? (I call it a lot of times and it could result in some speed improvements)

```
def vectorr(I,  J,  K):
    vect = []
    for k in range(0,  K):
        for j in range(0, J):
            for i in range(0, I):
                vect.append([i, j, k])
    return vect
```

Comment: Will `K, J, I` be the same always?

Comment: Please give us some more context. Keep in mind that as programmers, there are probably a hundred different ways to handle this. Each way has different results that are more or less useful to you in the end, or in the future. The more information you give us (what you have tried, how this is used, what you want to get out of it), the better a solution you will get back.

Comment: Better yet, how do you know it needs improvement? Did you profile your application?

Comment: Yes, with cProfile. it takes about 5%-10% of the total time of executions(because I call a lot of times). And no, I,J,K change

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to take a look at [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

> Equivalent to nested for-loops in a generator expression. For example,
>   product(A, B) returns the same as ((x,y) for x in A for y in B).
>
> The nested loops cycle like an odometer with the rightmost element
>   advancing on every iteration. This pattern creates a lexicographic
>   ordering so that if the input’s iterables are sorted, the product
>   tuples are emitted in sorted order.

Also no need in 0 while calling range(0, I) and etc - use just range(I)

So in your case it can be:

```
import itertools

def vectorr(I,  J,  K):
    return itertools.product(range(K), range(J), range(I))
```

Comment: The best answer to nearly any question with the words "python" and "loop" in it is going to be "itertools".

Comment: itertools is an awesome module)

Comment: `[i, j, k] for i, j, k` should be `[i, j, k] for k, j, i`

Comment: Collapsing to a list is probably a bad idea here - might be better to return a generator expression

Comment: @Eric thanks, for your corrections, i simpy returned list since OP returned a list

Comment: Sure, but the answer to "How can i made this function faster?" is probably "Don't allocate I*J*K lists all at once"

Answer (score 2):

You said you want it to be faster.  Let's use NumPy!

```
import numpy as np

def vectorr(I, J, K):
    arr = np.empty((I*J*K, 3), int)
    arr[:,0] = np.tile(np.arange(I), J*K)
    arr[:,1] = np.tile(np.repeat(np.arange(J), I), K)
    arr[:,2] = np.repeat(np.arange(K), I*J)
    return arr
```

There may be even more elegant tweaks possible here, but that's a basic tiling that gives the same result (but as a 2D array rather than a list of lists).  The code for this is all implemented in C, so it's very, very fast--this may be important if the input values may get somewhat large.

Comment: And `return arr.tolist()` if you need the results as lists instead of a numpy array.

Comment: would this be more efficient than itertools.product?

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are more thorough and, in this specific case at least, better, but in general, if you're using Python 2, and for large values of I, J, or K, use `xrange()` instead of `range()`. `xrange` gives a generator-like object, instead of constructing a list, so you don't have to allocate memory for the entire list.

In Python 3, `range` works like Python 2's `xrange`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy

def vectorr(I,J,K):
   val = numpy.indices( (I,J,K))
   val.shape = (3,-1)
   return val.transpose() # or val.transpose().tolist()
```